# ASP classic to create a folder, and then change the permissions on it

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I am relatively new to this whole ASP classic programming thing, and I am not working on a pretty complex script. Essentially the script creates a domain user account, and then creates their home folder on a networked machine. I.E: \SERVER\DIR\HOMEDIR.

I have the code working marvelously, except when it comes to making their home directory. It creates the folder, yet it gets and access denied error when it comes to the permissions change. I even have another code that will move the folder and its contents from one directory to another. I have done everything I can think of, the IUSR_MACHINE account even is a domain administrator.

The code is below. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greately appreciated!

The strHomeFolder is of the form: \SERVER\DIR\DIR with two backslashes at the beginning. I have also tried this on the local server with a local path (C:\DIR\DIR) but that did not work either, same access denied.

Thank you,

Levi

```
Sub HomeDir()
        %>
        <br/>
        Inside of Homedir()<br/>


        <%
strHomeFolder = strHome & strUser
Set objFSO = server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
If strHomeFolder <> "" Then
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strHomeFolder) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    objFSO.CreateFolder strHomeFolder
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         'On Error GoTo 0
         'Wscript.Echo "Cannot create: " & strHomeFolder
         End If
    'On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    If objFSO.FolderExists(strHomeFolder) Then
                %>
        <br/>
        folder exists<br/>
        strHomeFolder = <%=strHomeFolder%><br/>
        strUser = <%=strUser%><br/>

        <%
    'Assign user permission to home folder.
    cmdtxt = "%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " & strHomeFolder & " /t /c /g Administrators:F " & "SYSTEM:F engineering2\" & strUser & ":F"
    intRunError = 25
    intRunError = objShell.run(cmdtxt, 2, True)
                %>
        <br/>
        intRunError = <%=intRunError%><br/>


        <%
        If intRunError <> 0 Then
        %>
        <br/>
        Calcs is balking.......intRunError = <%=intRunError%><br/>


        <%
        'Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
        '& strUser & " to home folder " & strHomeFolder
        End If
    End If    
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message? What happens if you try to run the exact same cacls command on a command line instead of from VBScript?

Comment: Hello Dan,

Well originally, intrunerror = 0, which would mean success, but it was not successful. I then isolated the calcs part in such a way that I could get the stdout output from a terminal and it would say: Are you sure (Y/N)? ACCESS_DENIED: \\SERVER\DIR\DIR. Same if it was local. I even tried to impersonate another user, per  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;248187, but that did not work. When I run the same exact code in command line, it executes just fine. I will try in VBScript now outside of asp.

Thanks,

Levi

Comment: I ran into the same problem with a tool that created permission groups and set permissions on folders for this group. In my case it turned out that the new group wasn't visible yet when executing (x)cacls so I had to build in a wait/sleep to get it to work. On a side note: Did you consider using PowerShell instead of cacls to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

have you given the DIR folder read/write access? this needs to be done on local and the server. Have you checked that permission?

Caio